# Дата и время на сервере. PHP

Tags: php, дата

Скрипт выполняется в назначенное время, при обработке файла использует сравнение текущей даты и времени с датой и временем из файла. При обновлении скрипта допустил ошибку и работа скрипта завершилась ошибкой. После исправления ошибки необходимо запустить скрипт, но сделать это необходимо так, чтобы скрипт думал что сейчас 02.07.2016 05:00. Можно ли как-то подменить серверное время не меняя время на  самом сервере?

Код сравнения дат

```
$goal_data = time() - 86400;

// если просрочена, сохраняем данные в структуру
if ($goal_data > strtotime($data_base)) {
```

Comment: можно сделать необязательный аргумент - "текущее время". Если не задан, то брать настояшее

Comment: Вопрос в том как поменять настоящее время средствами php

Comment: А как вы его получаете в PHP-скрипте? При помощи функции time()?

Comment: текущее время да, через time

Comment: Текст скрипта перед вами. Почти наверняка время спрашивается в одном месте. Поправьте эту строку, чтоб брал аргумент, если задан. запускайте указав время

Comment: что гадать предоставьте часть скрипта где вы это време берете сравниваете и т.д.

Comment: код добавил в вопрос

Comment: Походу надо в отпуск, затупил походу жестко :)

Comment: и прекращайте высчитывать время в секундах, в php 100 лет уже очень удобный ооп DateTime класс есть

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно поменять обработку времени в самом скрипте. Например:

```
$goal_data = empty($argv[1]) ? (time() - 86400) : ($argv[1] - 86400);
```

в таком случае при запуске из командной строки, например

```
php ./your_script.php 1467585948
```

первым аргументом 1467585948 будет "подменянное время".

Либо менять время на сервере, или писать отдельный скрипт копипастом.

Answer (score 1):

Если используете php не из консоли, еще один вариант:

```
$date = isset($_GET['date'])?strtotime($_GET['date']):time();//вместо strtotime можно использовать свою функцию
```

Тогда вызов будет примерно такой:

```
 file.php?date=02.07.2016//02 07 2016, 2 Jul 2016 и т.д.
```